# Approximate a one-form with nowhere vanishing one-forms having bounded Laplacians

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, singularity-theory

This is a follow-up question of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347616/approximate-a-one-form-on-the-disk-with-nowhere-vanishing-one-forms-satisfying-a).

Let $\mathbb{D}^2$ be the closed two-dimensional unit disk (endowed with some smooth Riemannian metric), and let $\sigma \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ be a smooth one-form.

> Does there exist a sequence of smooth one-forms $\sigma_n \in  \Omega^1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ such that
>
> 1. $\sigma_n \to \sigma$ in $L^2$.
> 2. $\sigma_n$ do not vanish on  $\mathbb{D}^2$.
> 3. $\sup_n \|\delta d \sigma_n \|_{L^p}< \infty,  \sup_n \| d \delta \sigma_n \|_{L^p}< \infty$ for *some* $p>1$.

Note that I don't fix any boundary conditions on $\sigma_n$, so we don't have standard elliptic estimates. (In particular, $\sup_n \|\Delta  \sigma_n \|_{L^p}< \infty$ does not imply $\sup_n \|\nabla^2  \sigma_n \|_{L^p}< \infty$).

**Comment:**

I think that one can [make a perturbation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345652/46290) to $\sigma$ which gives a form with only finitely many zeroes. After that, there is a [procedure to push out the zeroes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433870/can-we-approximate-a-vector-field-on-the-plane-with-non-vanishing-vector-fields/3439203#3439203), one by one -- by composing with diffeomorphisms. I think that this procedure does not satisfy condition $3$.

---

If it matters, I am fine with assuming that $\delta \sigma=0, d\sigma=0$.

Note that we [cannot approximate](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346238/can-we-approximate-a-vector-field-on-the-plane-with-non-vanishing-vector-fields) $\sigma$ by nowhere-vanishing $\sigma_n$ in $W^{1,1}$.

Comment: While you don't have a global elliptic estimate, there should be a local elliptic regularity estimate. I don't have a good reference but http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/246B/lecs/246B_ch5.pdf Theorem 5.3 is the sort of thing you could use. (Then with a $W^{2,p}$ bound you can use the Rellich–Kondrachov theorem.)

Comment: Thank you, you are right. These local estimates are exactly what I needed. It seems then that my final goal is not really achievable. However, I certainly learned a lot from all your great answers, even if I won't "use" them in any tremendous way for some paper (which probably won't be written now...). Thank you very much again.