# Is there an area-preserving diffeomorphism of the disk which is nowhere conformal?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

This question is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557359/does-there-exist-a-volume-preserving-diffeomorphism-of-the-disk-without-conforma). Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the **closed** unit disk.

> Does there exist a smooth area-preserving diffeomorphism $f:D \to D$ that does not have conformal points?

I want the singular values $\sigma_i$ of $df$ to be everywhere distinct, and $\det(df)=1$.

---

It is proven [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345652/46290) that for any map $f:D \to \mathbb R^2$, the condition of being with distinct singular values is 'generic' in the following sense: There exist $f_n \in C^{\infty}(D, \mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $W^{1,2}(D, \mathbb{R}^2)$ and $df_n$ has distinct singular values everywhere on $D$.

It seems to me that this approximation procedure, applied to a map $f \in \text{Diff}(D)$, does not guarantee that the $f_n$ will map $D$ into $D$, let alone be diffeomorphisms. (e.g. I think that the convergence $f_n \to f$ cannot be made uniform in general). However, perhaps this genericity phenomena can still be used somehow.

---

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393599/46290) provides the following example for a one-parameter family of such diffeomorphisms $D\setminus \{0\} \to D \setminus \{0\}$:

$$f_c: (r,\theta)\to (r,\theta+c\log r).$$ This description is given in terms of polar coordinates both in the domain and the range. For each non-zero $c ֿ\in \mathbb R$ we get a diffeomorphism, with fixed distinct singular values whose product is $1$.

---

**Edit:**

Can we answer the infinitesimal version of the question? That is, let $f_t$ be a smooth family of area-preserving diffeomorphisms. Does each $f_t$ has a conformal point? [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393599/46290) treats the "formally infinitesimal" case.

Comment: Maybe a fixed point theorem could be used.

Comment: I don't know the concepts you refer to, but is a nonconformal map the same as a map with no conformal points?

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to prove an infinitesimal version where an area preserving diffeomorphism is replaced by a Hamiltonian vector field.
Let H be a function in the unit disc, constant on the boundary. Consider the Hamiltonian vector field $(H_y,-H_x)$ and the respective infinitesimal diffeomorphism
$(x,y) \mapsto (x+\epsilon H_y, y-\epsilon H_x).$
When is it conformal at a point? When the Jacobian is a dilation. That is, if the matrix is
$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}$,
then $a=d, b+c=0$. In our case, the Jacobian is
$\begin{pmatrix}
1+\epsilon H_{xy}& \epsilon H_{yy}\\
-\epsilon H_{xx}& 1-\epsilon H_{xy}.
\end{pmatrix}$.
Hence we want to find solutions of
$H_{xx}=H_{yy}, H_{xy}=0.$
Consider the vector field $V:=(H_{xx}-H_{yy}, 2H_{xy})$. If it has zero on the boundary, we are done. If not, let's calculate it in polar coordinates $(\alpha,r)$ on the boundary circle $r=1$. Chain rule calculations simplify by the fact that, on the boundary, $H_\alpha=0$. My calculation yields:
$V = H_{rr} (\cos 2\alpha, \sin 2\alpha).$
The index of this field equals 2, so there are two zeroes, multiplicities counted, inside the disc.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting approach. However, there is something that I don't understand: $
(x,y) \mapsto (x+\epsilon H_y, y-\epsilon H_x)$ is not the exact $\epsilon$ time flow of the vector field $(H_y,-H_x)$; it is only a formal approximation of it, right? So it is not clear to me that this actually answers the continuous version of the question regarding the flow of a divergence-free vector field.

Comment: In other words, one could ask the following question: Let $\phi_{\epsilon}$ be a smooth family of area-preserving diffeomorphisms. Does each $\phi_{\epsilon}$ have a conformal point? Does your argument answers this version of the question? I am not sure of it, since the map you describe is not really the flow of the vector field.

Comment: I's similar to the divergence of a vector field. Given a diffeomorphism of a manifold with a volume form, one can ask how it distorts the volume at every point; the answer is that it's the determinant of the Jacobian. For an infinitesimal diffeomorphism, that is, a vector field, one considers its $\epsilon$-flow, calculates the respective Jacobian, and takes the first non-trivial term in $\epsilon$ (of degree 1), which is the divergence of the field.

Comment: OK, thanks. But I still don't understand something. We want to prove that the $\epsilon$-flow $\phi_{\epsilon}$ has conformal points, right? that is we want to prove that $d\phi_{\epsilon}(x)$ is conformal for some point $x$ in the disk. It seems to me that you have proved that $d\tilde \phi_{\epsilon}$ has a conformal point, where $\tilde \phi_{\epsilon}(x,y) := (x+\epsilon H_y, y-\epsilon H_x)$ is a first-order approximation of $\phi_{\epsilon}$. So, I am asking: can we deduce from that the original "true" $d \phi_{\epsilon}$  has conformal points?

Comment: That is: Is it true that if $\tilde \phi_{\epsilon}$ has conformal points, then so does $ \phi_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: No, the infinitesimal version doesn't imply the truth of the original "finite" conjecture. Another analogy that might be helpful: there are various results in symplectic topology claiming that certain symplectomorphisms of closed symplectic manifolds have fixed points. An infinitesimal version is that a Hamiltonian vector field has zeros, and this is easy: these zeros are the critical points of the Hamiltonian function. Arnold's conjectured in the 1960s that the "finite" versions also held, and this stimulated the development of symplectic topology in the 1980s and later.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure: I of course understand that even the "true"/"full" infinitesimal version - which is a question about a family $\phi_{\epsilon}$ of area-preserving maps, does not settle the question of existence of some diffeo' which does not need to be part of a flow. Furthermore, what you have solved was something weaker than the true flow version of the question, i.e. something which I might call 'formally infinitesimal', right? I do understand that this *is* a good step in the right direction. I just wanted to know whether this can be immediately pushed to the (true) flow-version.

Comment: It seems that this is not immediate. I will now take some time to understand the rest of the details of your answer. Thanks again.